# @OnApplicationStart not working in Play framework

Tags: playframework

I have a class

```
@OnApplicationStart
public class OnStartManager extends Job{
    private DataGridServiceManager  dataGridServiceManager = null;
    @Override
        public void doJob() {

               dataGridServiceManager = DataGridServiceManagerImpl.getInstance();
       }

}
```

This is executing when the application starts, but it also executes when i access other pages or even the same page. But i want to execute it only once during the start of the application. What should i do to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running in DEV mode, Play sometimes automatically restarts the application. This will cause the `@OnApplicationStart` jobs to be rerun as well. Maybe this is what you are experiencing?

Quote from [Jobs section of Play documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/jobs):

> When you run the application in DEV mode, the application waits for
>   the first HTTP request to start. Moreover when you are in DEV mode,
>   **the application will sometimes automatically restart when needed**.

Comment: +1 although little information in the question, this is almost certainly going to be the reason for this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I do processing of some information and storing before my `index.html` loads. I used the `@OnApplicationStart` tag for my `bootstrap.java` file. It works without a sweat.